# Can someone help explain how to simplify logs of different bases?

Tags: logarithms

So, I have a question here:

$\log_2 M + \log_3 N$

The goal is to simplify this as far as possible. I tried to do change of base, but that didn't really help. I thought of rearranging and manipulating it with the laws of log, namely the following:

$\log_a(bc)=\log_ab+\log_ac$

$\log_a(b/c)=\log_ab−\log_ac$

$\log_ab^n=n\log_ab$

$\log_ab=1/\log_ba$

$(\log_ab)(\log_bc)=\log_ac$

$\log_aa=1$

I tried a few methods, but I couldn't really make any progress. Can anyone help?

Comment: Getting one single logarithmic term is not possible, but converting everything into log base 10, is. See answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use change of base formula on both given logarithms, and then make a common denominator: $\frac{\log M}{\log2}+\frac{\log N}{\log3}$=$\frac{1}{(\log2)(\log3)}$$(\log3\log M+\log2\log N)$

Answer (score 0):

You can try $$\log_2M + \log_3N=\frac{\log M}{\log2}+\frac{\log N}{\log3}=\log(M^{\frac{1}{\log2}})+\log(N^{\frac{1}{\log3}})=\log(M^{\frac{1}{\log2}}N^{\frac{1}{\log3}}).$$

Comment: After the first $=$ sign, things go wrong. You used the change of base formula (the intend is ok) incorrectly

Comment: What would you do to change that then?

Comment: @imranfat, actually the error is in the first equality; it should be $\log_2M+\log_3N=(\log_2e)\log M+(\log_3e)\log N$ (assuming $\log$ means $\log_e$). If you make that correction, then everything is OK.

Comment: @BarryCipra Yes you are right. My wording was poorly chosen, but when my eyes passed that first equal sign, I misswallowed and I stopped reading the rest. I think the intention was good though, the use of change of base.

Comment: $\log_2M + \log_3N=\frac{\log M}{\log 2}+\frac{\log N}{\log 3}$

Comment: @imranfat, agreed, the basic idea is good. I had to check and doublecheck where the $\log_2e$ and $\log_3e$ belonged, since I usually get things wrong on the first attempt.

Comment: My bad! It should be corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is that
$\log_a (b) 
=\dfrac{\log_c(b)}{\log_c(a)}
$
holds for any $c$.
So you can choose
the most convenient $c$.

Also note that
this implies that
$\log_b(a)\log_a(b) = 1
$
so that
$\log_a (b) 
=\log_c(b)\log_a(c)
$.

So

$\begin{array}\\
\log_2 M + \log_3 N
&=\dfrac{\log_c M}{\log_c 2} + \dfrac{\log_c N}{\log_c 3}\\
&=\log_c M\log_2 c + \log_c N\log_3 c\\
&=\log_c M^{\log_2 c} + \log_c N^{\log_3 c}\\
&=\log_c (M^{\log_2 c} N^{\log_3 c})\\
\end{array}
$

Choose $c=2$ or $c=3$
to simplify this a little.